# reconfigure bsd-mailx on ubuntu

Tags: email, ubuntu, apt-get, command-line-interface, mailx

I tried `apt-get remove bsd-mailx` and `apt-get purge bsd-mailx`
to see if with `apt-get install bsd-mailx`I would get the default configuration screen of it, but don't get it. How might I get to completely remove bsd-mailx to get once again the configuration screen, or how to toggle the configuration screen somehow as when it is first installed to apply a different configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow bsd-mailx
```

Comment: My guess, the user asked about "the default configuration screen" which actually refers to **postfix configuration screen**. As it is the only screen displayed at installation time of **apt-get install bsd-mailx**.

Answer (score 2):

Debian **bsd-mailx** package uses **postfix** as default agent (service) for outside of localhost mail delivery. If you missed config step or wish to re-configure bsd-mailx, do:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

Check you running config **/etc/postfix/main.cf** and service status

```
sudo service postfix status
```